# Loading Dojo Library from AOL and Widget Codes from Local?

Tags: dojo

I just started to learn Dojo. I followed one site Widget example with some different ways to load Dojo libraries. I like to use AOL reference to load dojo.js like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.2.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js">
</script>
```

and saved my widget codes in local web server like this:

```
scripts/
   myWidget/
     widgetExample.js
   ...
test.html
```

where *widgetExample.js* contains my widget class codes, and *test.html* is my testing page. The error message I got is: "uncaught exception: Could not load cross-domain resources: *myWidget.widgetExample* ...". I am not sure if I have to load dojo package locally? I really like to separate dojo library package as they are or loaded from AOL and only put my own codes in a local path. I tried to google about different domain loading, baseScriptUrl, and moduleMapping? Still not be able to figure out. Thanks for any detail instructions if any.

Answer (score 3):

This may help: http://dojotoolkit.org/forum/dojo-core-dojo-0-9/dojo-core-support/xdomain-usage-dojo-loading-not-detecting-local-modules

The summary is: you need a djConfig item registering the modulePaths you want to be local, and specify a baseUrl to "trick" Dojo into thinking it knows where those paths are relative, across hosts.

djConfig = { modulePaths: { "mine":"/js/mine" };

then you can dojo.require("mine.Thing") from /js/mine/Thing.js

Regards,
Peter Higgins

Comment: A couple of things that I would like to add. I needed to set baseUrl: './' otherwise the 'xd' string was inserted into my require path. Secondly, djConfig must be defined before loading Dojo.