# How to write my widget without declaring it's code in dojo.ready

Tags: javascript, widget, dojo

Using some tutorials I wrote simple widget but it causes error "declare customwidget.TestDijit: mixin #0 is unknown":

//test.html

```
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Test.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

dojo.require("customwidget.TestWidget");

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div dojoType='customwidget.TestWidget'/>
</body>
```

//test.js

```
dojo.provide('customwidget.TestDijit')
dojo.require('dijit._Widget');
dojo.require('dijit._Templated');
dojo.require('dojo.caсhe');

dojo.declare("customwidget.TestDijit",  [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated],
{
    //can't use  dojo.caсhe('customwidget.template', 'testdijit.html') I don't know why
    templatePath : "",
    widgetsInTemplate : true,
    lang : 'EN',
    postCreate: function(args, frag)
    {
        this.inherited('postCreate', arguments);
    },
    clickEvent : function()
    {
        alert("Button Click event");
    }
});
```

//testdijit.html

```
<div id="${id}">
<input dojoattachevent="onClick: clickEvent" dojotype="dijit.form.Button" label="Search" />
</div>
```

I found out that if I place all widget's code in the dojo.ready funciton, then it will work(thank to [this article](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/templated/)). Of course, I don't want to locate all my js code in the ready function. In the mentioned article's code sample authors wrote `// Future tutorials will explain how to properly separate this out into its own file.`
Do you know how to solve this problem?

PS. Do you also know why I can't use dojo.cashe in the this js code?

UPD: Problems with loading cross-domain resources. 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308036/loading-dojo-library-from-aol-and-widget-codes-from-local) is similar discussion but I couldn understand how to solve the problem. I can store dojo localy but in this case it couldn't find my TestWidget.js - I don't how I can specify the path to my scipts. If I do that using baseUrl it will say "Could not load 'dojo._base.lang'; last tried './_base/lang.js'".

test/test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css"> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" 
    djConfig="parseOnLoad:true, baseUrl: './'">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    dojo.require("customwidget.TestWidget");

</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div dojoType='js.Test'>
    </div>
</body>
```

test/customwidget/TestWidget.js

```
dojo.provide('customwidget.TestWidget')
dojo.require('dijit._Widget');
dojo.require('dijit._Templated');
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
//dojo.require('dojo.cache');

dojo.declare("customwidget.TestWidget",  [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated],
{
    templatePath : "",//dojo.cache('customwidget.template', 'testdijit.html'),
    widgetsInTemplate : true,
    lang : 'EN',
    postCreate: function(args, frag)
    {
        this.inherited('postCreate', arguments);
    },
    clickEvent : function()
    {
        alert("Button Click event");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things first (but I'm guessing these are mostly typos you made when posting here).

- `dojo.cashe` should be `dojo.cache`
- you seem to mix `customwidget.TestWidget` with `customwidget.TestDijit`
- if you want to use `dijit.form.Button` in your widget's template, you have to require it

Now onto the more important matters. When you use a <script> tag to include the js file, Dojo doesn't take care of loading requirements before doing anything else. That's why you get mixin unknown, because in the call to `dojo.declare`, the class `dijit._Templated` is not yet loaded.

However, if you use dojo.require to load your widgets/modules, dojo makes sure the requirements (all the dojo.require statements) in *Test.js* are done loading before trying to use them. So, remove your <script>-tag for *Test.js*.

Now we need to tell `dojo.require` where your files can be found. You are using dojo from a CDN (googleapis), so by default, Dojo will actually try to load

```
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/...../1.6.0/customwidget/TestWidget.js".
```

That's not right at all! Rename your *Test.js* to *TestWidget.js* and put it in a folder called *customwidget*. This is the Dojo convention for module paths. If your widget was called `customwidget.coolwidgets.TestWidget`, it should be in *customwidget/coolwidgets/TestWidget.js*.

For now, put this folder next to your HTML file. Then add the following to your `djConfig`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true, baseUrl: './' ">
</script>
```

This tells `dojo.require` to start looking for widgets in the same folder as your HTML file, and not on the server where you are loading Dojo itself from. Since we put the *customwidget* folder next to out HTML file, that should work fine.

In your `dojo.cache` call you are using `customwidget.template` and *testdijit.html*. That means your *testdijit.html* file has to be placed in *customwidget/template/*

---

**Edit:** Here's a setup that works correctly on my machine.

Folder structure:

```
test/
   test.html
   customwidget/
      TestWidget.js
```

test.html:

```
<html>                                                                                                            
  <head>                    
    <link rel="stylesheet"                                                                                           
      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad:true,baseUrl: './'"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("customwidget.TestWidget");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <div dojoType='customwidget.TestWidget'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

TestWidget.js

```
dojo.provide('customwidget.TestWidget');

dojo.require('dijit._Widget');
dojo.require('dijit._Templated');
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

dojo.declare("customwidget.TestWidget",  [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {
     templateString: "<div>Foobar<br/><button dojoType='dijit.form.Button'>Yeah</button></div>",
     widgetsInTemplate : true
 });
```

Comment: OK, that pretty much nails it. I'll remove my answer.

Comment: I modified the code like you said but have got errors "Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012", "Could not load 'js.Test'; last tried '../customwidget/Test.js'", "uncaught exception: Could not load cross-domain resources: js.Test". Folder "customwidget" is in the same folder where html is located.

Comment: @Kirill Lykov Is your widget called Test or TestWidget? The filename needs to be the same (only with .js at the end). What do you dojo.require? Are you sure you added baseUrl to your djConfig?

Comment: @Frode Yes, folder's name is customwidget, file name is Test.js and class name is customwidget.Test. And djConfig has been modified. To sort this problem out I tried to copy dojo localy but this caused other errors.

Comment: @Kirill Lykov Update your question with your new code, it's hard for me to assume what's wrong without seeing your code. Judging from the error, you have a misspelling somewhere. Both dojo.require, dojo.provide and dojo.declare now say "customwidget.Test", right? And baseUrl is "./" (only one dot)?

Comment: @Kirill Lykov `<div dojoType='js.Test'>` Whyyyyy? :P This should be `<div dojoType="customwidget.Test">`. Yes, things are a little bit different if you have Dojo locally.

Comment: Regarding the other question you have linked to: If you have a local copy of Dojo, and your customwidget folder is *not* in the same folder as dojo, dijit and dojox, you must use `registerModulePath` to tell Dojo where your code is. But, when you're using a CDN, it's enough to set the baseUrl.

Comment: @Frode About js.Test - it is artifact from my experiments with this code. If I write `customwidget.Test`, I'll have the same error.
About `registerModulePath` - where does it start looking for files?

Comment: @KirillLykov I updated my answer with an example that works on my machine. If it doesn't on yours, then I'm stumped. Here's a link about registerModulePath: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/registerModulePath.html . Like you can see from my example, it's technically not required for your code though.

Comment: @Frode Your example doesn't work on my mashine without additional djConfig attribure `modulePaths:{customwidget:'customwidget'}`. Thank you for your help any way. Finally, it works.

Comment: @Kirill Lykov That's odd, but I'm glad you got it working. Cheers.